# Ajax call only works from inside a php file and not with an url directly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, url

i have an issue with my web page to draw graph from REST server data.
my code is working if i do my ajax call with the url in a php file doing a simple file_get_contents.
However if i want to use an url directly the call to the rest server works but ajax return Object object.

this is working:

```
jsonData=$.ajax({
      url: "getData.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: text,
      async: false
      }).responseText;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML =jsonData;
```

this is not working

```
    jsonData=$.ajax({
      url: ""+text+"",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML =jsonData;
```

this is my getData.php :

```
$string = file_get_contents("http://localhost:5000/'Pi%202'/5/temperature/11.27.2017%2010:00/11.28.2017%2023:00");
```

echo $string;

The text contain the correct url as the get query to the rest server is successfull.
both are doing the get on the rest server but in the second jsonData is Object object. if i remove the responseText i get an undefined instead of Object object.
i have tried many kind of solutions proposed for this issues , i have tried the success function thing, which gave me no answer at all.
I have been stuck on this problems for over 2 days , it s the last part for my whole project to work and i m seriously considering giving it up or throw my computer.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: A few things... First, don't use `async: false`.  Keep your asynchronous code asynchronous.  By using the tools correctly you're less likely to encounter problems.  Second, what does `""+text+""` actually become?  You also omitted `data` from the second example, was that intentional?  Third, define "not working".  In what specific way does this fail?  Is the AJAX request made at all?  What exactly is the server's response?  Use the browser's debugging tools.

Comment: the ""+text+"" contains the url for the rest server to query data.
i use the jsonData to draw a graph with chart.js , in the first case i get my data back and the graph works , in the second case my data return Object object . both call are getting exacly the same answer from the rest server , so it must be javascript that does some crap.
i used async false because it wouldn't work any other way,....
i m not a working with web usually i cannot spend hour trying to understand why javascript does 2 different things when you enter the same data.

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools (looking at the network tab), is there any difference at all between the requests and responses of these two examples?  Does the requested URL change?  Does the included data change?  Do the headers change?  Does the response content change?  Do the response headers change?

Comment: the data field was an attempt to pass my url to the php file which failed totally. it s presence makes no difference in this case.

Comment: Well, the first recommendation would be to eliminate the variable of using AJAX incorrectly in the first place.  Remove the `async: false` and perform the follow-up actions in the `success` handler or in the `.done()` handler.  Aside from that, perhaps we need to better understand the goal of what you're trying to accomplish here.  If the first code sample works, why are you changing it at all?

Comment: in the one that fails i get a :
jquery.min.js:6 Failed to load http://localhost:5000/'Pi%201'/14/temperature/2017.11.28%2017:41:07/2017.11.28%2019:00:07: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
i m changing it because i need to be able to change this url depending on the sensor and value i wish to print , the text is an url that i put together with information from a form. In the getData.php the url is hardcoded.

Comment: What on earth is that URL?  One thing it's certainly *not* is `getData.php`.  So I guess there's your problem... `text` doesn't contain the information you assume it does.

Comment: it s a REST query , it s exactly the same one that is hardcoded in getData.php

Comment: I don't know how else to explain this... The string `http://localhost:5000/'Pi%201'/14/temperature/2017.11.28%2017:41:07/2017.11.28%2019:00:07` and the string `getData.php` are two very different strings.  Either you're drastically misunderstanding how these things work or you're providing very incomplete and misleading information about the problem.

Comment: i edited my post to show you the content of getData.php

Comment: On what URL is the active page loaded?  Does "localhost" mean the same thing in both contexts?  (Hint: It won't once you deploy your PHP to any server outside of your local development environment.)  The error indicates that you're trying to access a different host (could be as simple as a different port number) than the host which loaded the page.  That would be a CORS issue, and simply Googling that error message would find *a lot* of information and ways to address it.

Comment: everything runs from localhost ,yes it seems like i need a cors proxy, but i fail to understand why i dont need it from inside a php file. If i understand right it s my browser that doesn't allow me access to the data because it thinks it s comming from unauthorised origin? is there any way to disable this check completely ?

Answer (score 0):

After considerable discussion in the comment thread on the question, it appears that we've determined the issue.  To clarify for future readers, the two AJAX requests in the question are *not* the same thing.  They make requests to *vastly different* URLs.

- One is making a request to the hosted PHP application, which internally makes its own HTTP request to another site and returns the response.
- The other is attempting to make a cross-origin AJAX request directly to that other site.  This is, of course, failing as a standard CORS error.

---

To specifically address the questions reached in the comment thread...

> why i dont need it from inside a php file

Because PHP isn't running in the web browser.  It's application code running on the server.  Which makes it architecturally no different than the web browser *itself* which, of course, is expected to be able to make HTTP requests.  There's no reason to impose cross-origin limitations there.

> it s my browser that doesn't allow me access

Correct.  This is a security measure to prevent sites from exploiting cross-origin requests.  (Imagine, for example, a site which embeds JavaScript that makes AJAX requests to all major banking sites, hoping that you're currently logged in to one.)

> is there any way to disable this check completely ?

By writing your own web browser.  The difficulty there will be in trying to convince your users to download and run your web browser instead of industry-standard ones.  If the primary compelling feature of your web browser is that users will be open to potential cross-origin request attacks, it's going to be an especially difficult sell.

---

Basically you're running into a very common thing in web application development.  The good news is that you already have a working version of what you're trying to do.  Your first version.  You can make AJAX requests back to your own server-side application all you like, and that server-side application can in turn make any request to external services that you like.

Comment: the php file and the ajax are calling the same REST server that also run locally on port 5000. the browser may think it s comming from elsewhere , but in fact they make both exactly the same call and get the same answer from the rest server. the Server answer with a 200 which should not cause problem with cors except if i have something stripping the header in the way.
Sadly the first version is not an option as i have no way to select the data to be displayed. Posting the url to the php wouldn t work aswell. only thing i see is using a cors proxy on the second solution but it s messy,....

Comment: @Ashuiegi: Does the AJAX request successfully complete if you strip the protocol and host from the URL?  What if you URL-encode the values?  (`/%27Pi%201%27/14/temperature/2017.11.28%201‌​7%3A41%3A07/2017.11.28%2019%3A00%3A07`)  If the hosts are in fact the same then it's possible that the URL is in a state that is being misinterpreted (such as those additional `:` characters throughout the URL).  But if the hosts are (even *technically*) different then it's a simple CORS problem.  Note that the question becomes moot as soon as this PHP site is hosted anywhere except localhost.

Comment: @Ashuiegi: *"the first version is not an option as i have no way to select the data to be displayed"* - That doesn't sound likely, but whatever logic you've defined outside the scope of this question is, well, outside the scope and entirely unknown here.  *"Posting the url to the php wouldn t work aswell"* - Equally an unlikely assertion.  You may need to re-think how you approach the design, but that doesn't mean what you want is *impossible*.  Just that the assumptions you've made thus far didn't get you there.

Comment: the url that is send to the rest server are correct and the same , i can see that on my server , it's the answer that get blocked for sure. the rest server is a flask python app, everything is run on the same machine. I know it must be possible to post data to the php , i have seens exemple but as soon as i add any line to my php file everything stop working and i get no debug error or anything to help me.

Comment: @Ashuiegi: *Insisting* that it must be correct doesn't actually *correct* the problem.  Yes, everything is run on the same machine.  But that doesn't make it the same *host* from the browser's perspective.  *"as soon as i had any line to my php file everything stop working"* - Then it sounds like you've made mistakes in your code. It happens, it's okay.  But giving up and trying to do something else that *by design* won't work clearly isn't the answer. I can understand your frustration, but at this point you're just arguing with your web browser. The web browser isn't going to change its mind.

Comment: i simply cannot scrap it and restart because i dont have enough time . it s just one of many project i have to advance on. the important part was the rest client and server, this web page is just to present the work. it will never be used again. of course a this point i would never do this the same way again but at the same time i m doing web once every two years at best and i don't have the luxury to relearn everything everytime. thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ashuiegi: Again, I can understand the personal feelings of frustration.  But unfortunately none of that is relevant to the actual technical problem you're attempting to solve.  There are a variety of things you *can* do to develop whatever it is you want to develop.  If you choose not to do that based on other priorities outside the scope of the problem itself, that's your choice.  As valid a choice as it is, it's irrelevant to the question.  Either way, we're very much digressing from the actual question here.  If you simply don't want to solve it, it's best to delete the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is really simple in the case of a REST server it turns out.

just add cors support to the python flask rest app and it will work.

simply add these lines to the rest server:

```
from flask_cors import CORS
CORS(app)
```

As i was thinking my code or the method i was using are good enough, the problem came from the fact that i didn't knew anything about cors and that my rest server would need it while running locally.